# license information for custom asp.net controls

Tags: asp.net, .net, drop-down-menu, web, custom-controls

I have created stylish asp.net controls and have placed the source code and dll at sourceforge . I want to know that, will it be any issue if i create asp.net controls and upload the dlls for free at some place. As far as i know .NET framework is free and we can create and publsh dlls without any issue.
Also, which license should i use to protect my work, i don't want any money but i want other developers to get interested in this project and work on it. 
source forge location of project is: https://sourceforge.net/p/aspnetcontrols/

Can you please review the sample controls at [this location](http://kp.bumbleb.in/Controls.aspx) and please let me know if its a good start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**License**

The GNU Library General Public License (LGPL) seems popular but there are a few to choose from.

or

This site uses the creative commons license which is also a good one http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/

**GAC**

If you want to easily add your dll to the GAC so that it only needs to be installed once on each computer then create a setup (msi) project and click the "File System Editor" button on the solution explorer.

In the file system explorer you will see the "Global Assembly Cache Folder". Add your dll to the "Global Assembly Cache Folder" and it will be automatically installed to the correct location when users run your msi.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can share your dll, you can use `Gacutil.Exe` this tools permit you to share assemblies about different project or application.

this permit to install your dlls in GAC.

link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ex0ss12c%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

License : http://jena.sourceforge.net/license.html

Comment: which license should i use for my project at source forge

Comment: You cna use Jena, i tested two years ago, it's good, Link : http://jena.sourceforge.net/license.html